# Issue with HTTP and HTTPS - Need to get AJAX working

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I have a site where the client recently added an SSL certificate, since he has done this it has broke some stuff on the site, noticeably a slider on the homepage of the site.

The only thing I can see in the console is a 'Mixed Content: The page at'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested and insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com...' This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I have no idea what this means - other than the obvious that I need to get these called over HTTPS.

I have never come across this before. I tried doing a force rewrite in .htaccess which didnt work and I cant seem to understand any stuff online.

Help please!

Thanks

Comment: Change any url that is listed with that error to use https, E.g.  `https://ajax.googleapis.com`

Comment: Yeah I get that. but how?

Comment: You need to edit whatever file contains the http url